# Hive query not working for more than 3 partitions

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Below is my hive query

```
'select substr(ltrim(date_ts),0,10) date_ts,
 sum(if(col1 = 'type1', 1, 0)) as type_1,
 sum(if(col1 = 'type2', 1, 0)) as type_2,
 sum(if(col1 = 'type3', 1, 0)) as type_3
 from table1
 GROUP BY substr(ltrim(date_ts),0,10) 
 ORDER BY date_ts;'
```

My table1(external table) is partitioned as (year string,month string, day string)

Below are my partitions

```
'year='2010',month='01',day='01'
 year='2010',month='01',day='02'
 year='2010',month='01',day='03'
 year='2010',month='01',day='04''
```

The query is completely working fine if i run it on 3 or less partitions. And when i add the 4th partition, it just gets stuck at map=92%. Unable to figure out why. And it is working on combination of any 3 partitions. I don't know if anyone has faced this issued before.

I am able to get below output.

```
' date        | type1  | type2     |type3 |
------------------------------------------
 2011-10-01   |    1   |  0        |  0   |
 2011-10-02   |    1   |  0        |  0   |
 2011-10-03   |    0   |  1        |  1   |'
```

The moment i add a 4th partition for day four, map is getting stuck at some 90% and it stays on like that even after 1 to 2 hrs.

**Expected output**

```
' date        | type1  | type2     |type3 |
------------------------------------------
 2011-10-01   |    1   |  0        |  0   |
 2011-10-02   |    1   |  0        |  0   |
 2011-10-03   |    0   |  1        |  1   |
 2011-10-05   |    0   |  1        |  0   |'
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

What are the four partitions?   Take a look if you end up with

```
__DEFAULT_PARTITION
```

which means that you had a null value in the partition column. That leads to skew which leads to .. slowness.

How to do this:

```
use <your_database>;
show partitions table table1;
```

Comment: I updated the question with my partitions. Please have a look at it. How to check whether i have a null value in my partition column or not?

Comment: You do not have any null partition values.  I do not have further suggestions at this time.